# How to disable warnings and notices by php.ini

Tags: php, error-handling, warnings

I write this code in php.ini to disable warnings and notices, but it is not working for me. `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING`.

Below is my error handling code of php.ini.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Error handling and logging ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; error_reporting is a bit-field.  Or each number up to get desired error
; reporting level
; E_ALL             - All errors and warnings (doesn't include E_STRICT)
; E_ERROR           - fatal run-time errors
; E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR  - almost fatal run-time errors
; E_WARNING         - run-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_PARSE           - compile-time parse errors
; E_NOTICE          - run-time notices (these are warnings which often result
;                     from a bug in your code, but it's possible that it was
;                     intentional (e.g., using an uninitialized variable and
;                     relying on the fact it's automatically initialized to an
;                     empty string)
; E_STRICT          - run-time notices, enable to have PHP suggest changes
;                     to your code which will ensure the best interoperability
;                     and forward compatibility of your code
; E_CORE_ERROR      - fatal errors that occur during PHP's initial startup
; E_CORE_WARNING    - warnings (non-fatal errors) that occur during PHP's
;                     initial startup
; E_COMPILE_ERROR   - fatal compile-time errors
; E_COMPILE_WARNING - compile-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_USER_ERROR      - user-generated error message
; E_USER_WARNING    - user-generated warning message
; E_USER_NOTICE     - user-generated notice message
;
; Examples:
;
;   - Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings
;
 error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING
;
;   - Show all errors, except for notices
;
; error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT
;
;   - Show only errors
;
; error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
;
;   - Show all errors, except coding standards warnings
;

; Print out errors (as a part of the output).  For production web sites,
; you're strongly encouraged to turn this feature off, and use error logging
; instead (see below).  Keeping display_errors enabled on a production web site
; may reveal security information to end users, such as file paths on your Web
; server, your database schema or other information.
;
; possible values for display_errors:
;
; Off          - Do not display any errors
; stderr       - Display errors to STDERR (affects only CGI/CLI binaries!)
; On or stdout - Display errors to STDOUT (default)
;
; To output errors to STDERR with CGI/CLI:
;display_errors = "stderr"
;
; Default
;
display_errors = On

; Even when display_errors is on, errors that occur during PHP's startup
; sequence are not displayed.  It's strongly recommended to keep
; display_startup_errors off, except for when debugging.
display_startup_errors = On

; Log errors into a log file (server-specific log, stderr, or error_log (below))
; As stated above, you're strongly advised to use error logging in place of
; error displaying on production web sites.
log_errors = On

; Set maximum length of log_errors. In error_log information about the source is
; added. The default is 1024 and 0 allows to not apply any maximum length at all.
log_errors_max_len = 1024

; Do not log repeated messages. Repeated errors must occur in same file on same
; line unless ignore_repeated_source is set true.
ignore_repeated_errors = Off

; Ignore source of message when ignoring repeated messages. When this setting
; is On you will not log errors with repeated messages from different files or
; source lines.
ignore_repeated_source = Off

; If this parameter is set to Off, then memory leaks will not be shown (on
; stdout or in the log). This has only effect in a debug compile, and if
; error reporting includes E_WARNING in the allowed list
report_memleaks = On

;report_zend_debug = 0

; Store the last error/warning message in $php_errormsg (boolean).
track_errors = Off

; Turn off normal error reporting and emit XML-RPC error XML
;xmlrpc_errors = 0
; An XML-RPC faultCode
;xmlrpc_error_number = 0

; Disable the inclusion of HTML tags in error messages.
; Note: Never use this feature for production boxes.
;html_errors = Off

; If html_errors is set On PHP produces clickable error messages that direct
; to a page describing the error or function causing the error in detail.
; You can download a copy of the PHP manual from http://www.php.net/docs.php
; and change docref_root to the base URL of your local copy including the
; leading '/'. You must also specify the file extension being used including
; the dot.
; Note: Never use this feature for production boxes.
;docref_root = "/phpmanual/"
;docref_ext = .html

; String to output before an error message.
;error_prepend_string = "<font color=#ff0000>"

; String to output after an error message.
;error_append_string = "</font>"

; Log errors to specified file.
;error_log = filename

; Log errors to syslog (Event Log on NT, not valid in Windows 95).
;error_log = syslog
```

Is there a the solution to the disappearing of warning and notices?

Answer (score 10):

According to [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) your method (`E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING`) should have worked to disable just notices and warnings. Make sure you restart PHP in order for the changes to work.

If that still doesn't work (for whatever reason), you could try `E_ERROR | E_PARSE` to show only errors.

Comment: After changing INI settings, one should only have to recycle the application pool.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure error reporting in runtime using [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function:

```
<?php
// Turn off warnings and notices
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);
```

Other interesting options for that function:

```
<?php

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// For PHP >=5.3 use: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Comment: This is correct if you're just trying to do this in PHP code, but doesn't answer the question, which is about how to do it in php.ini.

Comment: In php.ini there is the following parameter at line 465: error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT - And another thing that i noticed in mine php.ini is that it shows some examples... 

Maybe just replace what is after the = sign with the options above and follow the syntax presented on php.ini itself? Final result would be: error_reporting = E_ERROR & E_WARNING & E_PARSE

Answer (score 6):

why dont you just add 
`display_errors = off`
on the `php.ini`? thad should do the job

Answer (score 1):

I do this at the top of the php page.

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
```

but to make it more versatile, you can do this

```
$displayErrors = isset($_GET['displayErrors']) ? $_GET['displayErrors'] : '0'; 

if ( $displayErrors == '1' ) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 
} else {
    ini_set('display_errors', '0'); 
}
```